react-beautiful-dnd Invariant failed: Cannot find droppable entry with id
I'm having an issue using react-beautiful-dnd within a react-virtualized List. My app has sections, each with its own Droppable, and contains Draggable elements. The problem occurs when I try to drag an element over other sections.
This is a code snippet
<DragDropContext onDragEnd={onDragEnd}>
      <WindowScroller>
        {({ height, scrollTop }) => (
          <AutoSizer disableHeight>
            {({ width }) => (
              <List
                autoHeight
                height={height}
                width={width}
                rowCount={state.sections.length}
                rowHeight={cache.rowHeight}
                deferredMeasurementCache={cache}
                rowRenderer={rowRenderer}
                scrollTop={scrollTop}
              />
            )}
          </AutoSizer>
        )}
      </WindowScroller>
    </DragDropContext>

where rowRenderer looks like
const rowRenderer = ({ index, key, style, parent }) => {
    const section = state.sections[index];
    return (
      <CellMeasurer
        cache={cache}
        columnIndex={0}
        key={key}
        parent={parent}
        rowIndex={index}
      >
        {({ measure }) => (
          <div style={style} key={key}>
            <Droppable droppableId={section.id} key={section.id}>
              {(provided) => (
                <div
                  {...provided.droppableProps}
                  ref={provided.innerRef}
                >
                  <h3>{section.name}</h3>
                  {section.elements.map((element, index) => (
                    <Draggable
                      key={element.id}
                      draggableId={element.id}
                      index={index}
                    >
                      {(provided, snapshot) => (
                        <div
                          ref={provided.innerRef}
                          {...provided.draggableProps}
                          {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                       
                        >
                          <div>
                            <strong>{element.name}</strong> - Size:{" "}
                            {element.size}
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      )}
                    </Draggable>
                  ))}
                  {provided.placeholder}
                </div>
              )}
            </Droppable>
          </div>
        )}
      </CellMeasurer>
    );
  };

As soon as the virtualized list starts modifying the DOM, I get the error: "Invariant failed: Cannot find droppable entry with id".
I've created a sandbox so you could also reproduce the issue
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/d3jnh6?file=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2Fvirtualized.jsx%3A114%2C55
I expected to be able to drag items between sections without errors. For instance, dragging "Element 1" from "Section 1" to "Section 20" should work.
I've ensured that all droppable IDs are correct and properly wrapped, but the error persists whenever the virtualized list re-renders.
